# How can I get a DNS name for a GCE instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I have a Google Compute Engine instance which is uniquely identified:

```
name: updateservice
zone: us-central1-a
project: myproject
```

is there a way to access the instance via DNS name? Otherwise I need to whitelist it's IP everytime in Cloud SQL since it changes on reboot.

Comment: Why don't you assign a static IP to the instance? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: Or use the Cloud SQL proxy https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

Answer (score 4):

Compute Engine instances have a private DNS name within the VPC, but do not have a public DNS name. You must configure a DNS resource record for the instance at your DNS server if you want a public DNS name.

> Otherwise I need to whitelist it's IP everytime in Cloud SQL since it
> changes on reboot.

There are two solutions for Cloud SQL:

1. Assign a static IP address to the Compute Engine instance. [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)
2. Deploy the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy on the Compute Engine instance . [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

Method #2 is the recommended method because IP addresses do not need to be whitelisted and authentication is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

If you SSH to the VM and run the command `hostname -A` it will show you the VM's [internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#instance-fully-qualified-domain-names).

From the on-premise network, you can reach/ping the VM's internal DNS by setting up [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview).

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem of accessing Cloud SQL. Also, note that the internal DNS names would not be resolved by **only** setting up a VPN. Additional DNS configuration would be required for on-premises to resolve VPC DNS names (DNS forwarders, split-brain DNS, etc). In summary, your answer is incomplete or wrong depending on the problem being solved.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar use case but for working between VPC Compute instances.

As @salvinjr mentioned doing `hostname -A` from compute instance, can provide you an internal dns name for a compute instance

For

```
name: updateservice
zone: us-central1-a
project: myproject
```

It may look like this

> `updateservice`.us-central1-a.c.`myproject`.internal

Now, I am able to `ping` or `ssh` to other vms without the need for IPs.