# Connecting to Cloud SQL from a host without a fixed IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a server running at home but I haven't a fixed ip address. So, I use DDNS to update my domains DNS when IP changed, and it is working fine. My problem comes trying to access a MySQL instance, because currently it is using a VPC, so I need to update manually adding new IP as Authorized Network. I wonder if it is possible to do that with a API REST call, in that way I can add a crontab in my server to check changes each n minutes and update Authorized Networks.
I read Google documentation, but in my understanding (I am not an english speaker) it is possible just from an authorized network. Somebody can give me a clue?.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/72943547/12265927

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at installing and using [Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) on your local server. This will remove the need to keep updating Authorized Networks when your IP changes.

Answer (score 3):

> I wonder if it is possible to do that with a API REST call, in that
> way I can add a crontab in my server to check changes each n minutes
> and update Authorized Networks.

Google Cloud provides the Cloud SQL Admin API. To modify the authorized networks, use the **instances.patch** API.

[Google Cloud SQL Method: instances.patch](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/instances/patch)

Modify this data structure to change the authorized networks:

[Google Cloud SQL IP Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/rest/v1/instances#ipconfiguration)

You might find it easier to use the CLI to modify the authorized networks:

```
gcloud sql instances patch <INSTANCENAME> --authorized-networks=x.x.x.x/32
```

[gcloud sql instances patch](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch#--authorized-networks)

I do not recommend constantly updating the authorized networks when not required. Use an external service to fetch your public IP and compare with the last saved value. Only update Cloud SQL if your public IP address changed.

Common public services to determine your public IP address. Note you should randomly select one as these services can rate limit you. Some of the endpoints require query parameters to only return your IP address and not a web page. Consult their documentation.

- https://checkip.amazonaws.com/
- https://ifconfig.me/
- https://icanhazip.com/
- https://ipecho.net/plain
- https://api.ipify.org
- https://ipinfo.io/ip

Note: I recommend that you use the Google Cloud SQL Auth Proxy. This provides several benefits including network traffic encryption. The auth proxy does not require that you whitelist your network.

Refer to my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72943547/8016720) for more details